# How can I change the icons of cpp files in macOS?

Tags: c++, clion, macos-catalina

Clion is a super great C++ IDE which is cross-platform, but when I install it on my Mac, something terrible happend. Look at this:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

These icon looks terrible! How can I fix them? Maybe change to the default icon?
I works on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.
Thanks!

Comment: this is not programing question is is more like superuser topic

Answer (score 1):

On macOS the icon of each file type is determined by the application that opens it by default. You can't override this unless you actually modify the application.

Right click on CLion.app > Show package contents > Contents

There's a file `Info.plist`. If we open it and search for `CFBundleTypeExtensions` we can see the following (CLion 2021.3.2 on macOS Monterey) :

```xml
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>c</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>clion.icns</string>        
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>h</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>clion.icns</string>        
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
        </dict>
        ...
```

So for file extensions .c, .h, etc the icon used is `clion.icns` which can be found in the `Resources` folder. You can copy custom icns files there and modify those keys in `Info.plist` to force Finder to use your own custom icons.